# basic auth with rails-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, basic-authentication

I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong here, but this is what my application controller looks like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  include ActionController::MimeResponds                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "joeyjojo", :password => "shabadoo"
end
```

I can't figure out why my http_basic_authenticate_with is throwing this error:

```
undefined method `http_basic_authenticate_with' for ApplicationController:Class
```

I'm sure it's something simple, but I don't see it.  The MimeResponds is working just fine in other controllers.

Comment: Why you applicationcontroller inherited from actioncontroller::api?

Comment: This is using the [rails-api gem](https://github.com/spastorino/rails-api)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You have to include `ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods` instead, to have the methods available. [Here's the module in `ActionController::Base`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5e300f1121dd24204cf0586521f34632485fce15/actionpack/lib/action_controller/base.rb#L232)

Comment: Carlos, thanks, but if I do class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods then all of my routes suddenly throw "No route matches..." Am I doing the include wrong?

Answer (score 14):

If you have a Rails API, add this to your controller:

> include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "username", password: "passwd123"
```

I am using Rails 4.2.4 and my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved my day. How developer is supposed to know that? I could not find anything about that in Ruby documentation